# GET vs POST in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def home

        print "Custom   " + params
  end

end
```

When I am putting request via **GET** it's working (printing value of params), but for **POST** it's not working 
  I am getting an error **ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):**

My config/routes.rb is

```
PostTest::Application.routes.draw do
     root  :to => "page#home"
end
```

My aim is to extract key and values from a post Request, any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that the `protect_from_forgery` line is uncommented in `controllers/application_controller.rb` .

Then make sure that your POST request is transmitting the authenticity token defined in the `protect_from_forgery` line. The rails `form_tag` helpers do this automatically for you. If you don't want to use `form_tag` you can generate the authenticity tag manually like this:

```
tag(:input, :type => "hidden", 
    :name => request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, 
    :value => form_authenticity_token)
```

If this doesn't work, please post the code for the form that is sending the POST request.

Comment: I commented #protect_from_forgery from application_controller then

Comment: Just use the rails `form_tag` method to create your form.

Comment: If you don't want to use `form_tag` you can generate the authenticity tag manually like this `tag(:input, :type => "hidden", :name => request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, :value => form_authenticity_token)`

Answer (score 0):

If the answer to my above question == 'yes' -  try to toss <%= csrf_meta_tag %> into your page and/or layout...

Comment: I am using rails 3 . The solution  <%= csrf_meta_tag %> is not working

Comment: Yeah - was a little to aggressive on my part - that's primarily for unobtrusive javascript I believe. You should be getting the auth token for free if you used form_for in your form construction....